# How can I show the inbox of the default email client on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How can I show the inbox (or start page) of the default email client on Windows Phone 8.1?

I'm trying to invoke:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:"));
```

but this shows a new, empty email message instead of the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

For emailing you can use

```
EmailRecipient sendTo = new EmailRecipient()
{
   Address = myobject.EmailId
};
EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
mail.To.Add(sendTo);
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

A more detailed desc can be found in this [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paraswadehra/2014/08/21/how-to-send-email-from-your-windows-phone-8-1-app/)

You can also make use of Share. It gives the option of selecting how user want to share the information

```
DataTransferManager dtManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
dtManager.DataRequested += (s, x) =>
{
    x.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "You Title";
    x.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "YourBody";
    x.Request.Data.SetWebLink(new Uri("Your Link"));
};
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm looking for displaying the inbox. I need to provide the 'confirm your e-mail address' functionality for WP8.

Comment: You mean to say you are trying to open another app from inside your app where inbox is shown? Probably you are looking to integrate Windows Live SDK or check out [Outlook Api](https://dev.outlook.com/) it will give you the default login pages and confirmation pages. for example this app is trying to access these info do you want to allow etc...